# Laravel select model group by but without group nullable values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a model Products. In the table there are columns id,description,barcode,sizebarcode,price. sizebarcode column has some values and nullable values. I want to select all products and groupby sizebarcode. But its group all nullable values in to one. I want to omit nullable values.

I want to select all unique values in sizebarcode and with all nullable values

Controller.php

```
$products = Category::where('slug',$slug)->first()->products_front()->paginate(12);

    return view('page.shop',compact('products'));
```

Model.php

```
 public function products_front(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product','cat_id','id')
        ->groupBy('sizebarcode')
        ->orderBy('created_at','asc');
}
```

My table
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVxyT.png)

Result that i want to, only green values

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezmLK.png)

Comment: try `->where('sizebarcode', '!=', null)`

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that `groupBy()` method should be written after you get the query, not when you are in the middle of query so you should `groupBy()` after your `paginate()` method

Comment: No, I want to get all uniqe values from sizebarcode column, and also all values with null

Comment: I append image that i want to get

Comment: @Benfactor according to your requirements I Don't think `sizebarcode=US080101` will come into selected green values.Since it has duplicate values.

Comment: @NishantGupta I can select unique values, with groupby. But all nullable values also groupby into one row. I want to all null values without groupby